# Como pegar filho de div com contains

Tags: jquery, css

Nesse caso eu quero testar a div com class `name`, mas depois de testar quero que as alterações de CSS sejam feitas na div com class `teste`.

```
<div class="teste">
  <div class="name">um nome</div>
  <div class="outradiv">outra coisa</div>
</div>

  $(".text").on('keyup', function (e) 
  {
    $(".teste:contains('"+$(".text").val().toLowerCase()+"')").css("display", "block");
    $(":not(.teste:contains('"+$(".text").val().toLowerCase()+"'))").css("display", "none");
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que esses seletores vão baralhar a coisa. Podes fazer isso mais simples, verificando se o texto do elemento contem a string que queres.

Exemplo:

```js
$(".text").on('keyup', function(e) {
  var texto = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $(".teste").each(function() {
    var contem = $(this).text().indexOf(texto) > -1;
    $(this).find(".name").css("display", contem ? "block" : "none");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text">
<div class="teste">
  <div class="name">um nome</div>
  <div class="outradiv">uma coisa</div>
</div>

<div class="teste">
  <div class="name">outro nome</div>
  <div class="outradiv">outra coisa</div>
</div>
```

Para esconder `.teste` quando for digitado qualquer coisa que esteja em `.name` ou `.outradiv`:

```js
$(".text").on('keyup', function(e) {
  var texto = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $(".teste").each(function() {
    var contem = $(this).text().indexOf(texto) > -1;
    $(this).css("display", contem ? "block" : "none");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text">
<div class="teste">
  <div class="name">um nome</div>
  <div class="outradiv">uma coisa</div>
</div>

<div class="teste">
  <div class="name">outro nome</div>
  <div class="outradiv">outra coisa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Caso seja mais de uma div com a class `teste`, funcionaria da mesma forma ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia nesse caso talvez precise de um ajuste. O input é só 1 ou há um input por cada `.teste`?

Comment: tem apenas um input, e vários `.teste`

Comment: @LucasCarezia editei a resposta para funcionar com N `.teste`

Comment: Não funcionou bem como eu imaginava, vou tentar explica melhor, quando for digitado qualquer coisa que esteja em `.name` ou `.outradiv` quero que a div com a classe `.teste` suma.

Comment: @LucasCarezia isso ainda é mais simples. Vou juntar à resposta.

Comment: @LucasCarezia no meu código (segundo exemplo) nunca refiro `.outradiv` a lógica só toma em conta o conteudo da própria `.teste`.  Faz um jsFiddle com esse exemplo que posso dar uma olhada.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, eu apenas estava usando letras maiúsculas, obrigado.